# Error from GetSatelliteAssembly called on assembly that lives outside AppDomain paths

Tags: c#, localization, assemblies

The purpose of my application is to pick some localized strings from an assembly. Part of the specification is:

- The assembly is to be selected by the user at run-time
- The assembly is private one, i.e. not registered with GAC

The code I came up with is:

```
Assembly resAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"X:\PathToApp\Assembly.Name.dll");
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("es-MX");
Assembly satAssembly = resAssembly.GetSatelliteAssembly(ci);
```

The last line threw an exception:
Could not load file or assembly "Assembly.Name.resources" or one of its dependencies. The system can not find the file specified.

I have overcome the exception by copying the folders that contain the satellite assemblies to the application root.

I do not like this approach. Any alternative ideas?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Assembly.LoadFile` method doesn't use a binding context, so its dependencies aren't automatically found in its directory.

You can instead use `Assembly.LoadFrom`.

You can read Suzanne Cook's post on the differences between these two methods to obtain further information ([LoadFile vs. LoadFrom](http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/09/19/loadfile-vs-loadfrom.aspx)).